# Extra vertical space below table row when compressing line spacing

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a large table in which many of the cells have free-flowing text in paragraph form.  Rather than use `\midrule`'s to help the reader delineate between rows, I'm trying to compress the text line spacing within a table row and inject a bit of extra spacing between table rows.  I use the `spacing` environment (let me know if I'm abusing that term) to compress the line spacing.  Then I use the `\rule` command to create a zero width box character in the 1st cell of each table row in order to give it enough distance from the table row above.  However, even with the `\rule` command commented out (below), I'm finding an inexplicably lot of space between rows.  Can anyone point out where this is coming from?  Here is my MWE, which I compile with one invocation of "pdflatex tmp.tex":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
   >{\raggedright\begin{spacing}{0.75}}p{1.5in}<{\end{spacing}}
   >{\raggedright\begin{spacing}{0.75}}p{0.45in}<{\end{spacing}}
}
   \toprule
      World domination scheme
      &
      Linear, either +ve
   \tabularnewline\midrule
      Sum over in subtree, including multiple instances
      &
      1.8\
   \tabularnewline%\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over nothing in subtree, including multiple instances blah
      dee blah
      &
      3.6
   \tabularnewline%\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over adfasd in subtree, including multiple adfads asdf asdf 
      &
      8.4
   \tabularnewline
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space comes from the `spacing` environment you use in your columns. Instead of adding it there, you could enclose the whole `tabular` in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{0.75}
\begin{tabular}{
   >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}
   >{\raggedright}p{0.45in}
}
   \toprule
      World domination scheme
      &
      Linear, either +ve
   \tabularnewline\midrule
      Sum over in subtree, including multiple instances
      &
      1.8\
   \tabularnewline\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over nothing in subtree, including multiple instances blah
      dee blah
      &
      3.6
   \tabularnewline\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over adfasd in subtree, including multiple adfads asdf asdf 
      &
      8.4
   \tabularnewline
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to your approach, use `\setstretch` instead of `spacing` environment like:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{
   >{\raggedright\setstretch{0.75}}p{1.5in}
   >{\raggedright\setstretch{0.75}}p{0.45in}
}
```

Here is a comparison of both the methods. Right side tabular uses `\setstretch`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{
   >{\raggedright\begin{spacing}{0.75}}p{1.5in}<{\end{spacing}}
   >{\raggedright\begin{spacing}{0.75}}p{0.45in}<{\end{spacing}}
}
   \toprule
      World domination scheme
      &
      Linear, either +ve
   \tabularnewline\midrule
      Sum over in subtree, including multiple instances
      &
      1.8\
   \tabularnewline%\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over nothing in subtree, including multiple instances blah
      dee blah
      &
      3.6
   \tabularnewline%\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over adfasd in subtree, including multiple adfads asdf asdf
      &
      8.4
   \tabularnewline
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{
   >{\raggedright\setstretch{0.75}}p{1.5in}
   >{\raggedright\setstretch{0.75}}p{0.45in}
}
   \toprule
      World domination scheme
      &
      Linear, either +ve
   \tabularnewline\midrule
      Sum over in subtree, including multiple instances
      &
      1.8\
   \tabularnewline%\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over nothing in subtree, including multiple instances blah
      dee blah
      &
      3.6
   \tabularnewline%\rule{0pt}{0.2in}%
      Sum over adfasd in subtree, including multiple adfads asdf asdf
      &
      8.4
   \tabularnewline
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This is a nice alternative...not quite enough space (probably because the inter-line spacing affects inter-row spacing, but I'm just guessing), but it does have the benefit of cleaning up the LaTeX code in the body of the table.

Comment: Drat...it doesn't look like it is possible to designate 2 answers as *the* answer.